# MySQL paginating results, cache or nocache?

Tags: mysql, caching

Using MySQL, I have a number of queries that look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_clause ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_clause ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_clause ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_clause ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 3000
```

and so on. The key point is that I am paginating through the result set. Each offset will only ever be executed once, so there's no point in caching it. However, I will eventually iterate through all the results. I care very much about polluting our query cache in this situation.

If I add SQL_NO_CACHE, this will cause MySQL to stop caching the results. Is this the most efficient, as each specific result set will only be used once? Or is MySQL smart enough to cache the entire result set once, pulling subsets based on the limit and offset with each request?

In other words, if I do not use SQL_NO_CACHE, would the four example SQL statements above result in one query and three cached responses, or would it result in four separate uncached queries?

Comment: with limit, it'll still have to fetch all of the `id` and `some_claus` fields so it can do the appropriate filtering. And since you're using the id for an ordering, it has to fetch ALL of the `id` fields to ensure things are ordered properly. Allowing it to cache at least that much would improve performance somewhat, otherwise you're essentially forcing a partial-fulltable scan.

Comment: If you are thinking about caching, you should definitely consider optimizing these queries. As already noted by Marc B `ORDER BY` greatly reduces the performance of the query. Even if you would fix that, `LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 10000` has to find 11000 lines to return 1000. Consider storing pagination data in the database.

Comment: We have to use ORDER BY. Without, we cannot reliably paginate over the results because MySQL does not guarantee the order. Trust me when I say leaving out the ORDER BY works almost all, but NOT ALL, of the time.

Comment: Marc B, are you saying that leaving out the SQL_NO_CACHE _will_ result in MySQL being able to cache? If so, please write it up as an answer, _ideally_ with supporting info and I will happily +1 it.

Jannis Froese, what do you mean by "consider storing pagination data in the database"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MySQL's documentation on query caching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html), "If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again."

Specifically, the following two statements are considered different, even though they differ only in capitalisation, and so would not be cached:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
Select * from tbl_name
```

As such, it is clear that, in my question above, adding SQL_NO_CACHE is the correct thing to do, as MySQL's query cache is useless here.